# How to logout and leave no traces of SESSION cookie?

Tags: php, session

I'm unlogging users with this code:

```
<?
   session_start();
   session_destroy();
?>
```

However doing it leaves a PHPSESSID cookie in the browser. What is this? Is there a way to make sure there are no traces of it at all?

I also tried:

```
session_start();
session_unset();
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
setcookie(session_name(),'',0,'/');
session_regenerate_id(true);
```

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: How did you check that? The `setcookie(...)` line should've worked. Did you use `session_set_cookie_params()` when creating it?

Comment: session_start(); literally sends a header to client, you not need session_start() if you not use session (did you saw **headers already sent error** ? meditate on that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `session_unset()` before using `session_name()` in your clearing call to `setcookie()` is likely to be the problem.  It removes all your session variables, leaving your setcookie call to operate on the wrong, or no, cookie.